# Ignore a query string after a file extension jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, google-analytics

I am using a script found here: http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/04/how-to-track-downloads-in-google-analytics/ to dynamically add a Google Analytic tracking code to links pointing to PDF documents.

I have implemented it and realized that the PDF documents in this site all have a query string appended to the end of the URL. Unfortunately, this script doesn't recognize the documents to be PDF because of the query strings. I need to modify this script to ignore the query string after the .pdf file extension, but am having trouble doing so. Below is the script which I have modified slightly:

```
var filetypes = /\.(pdf?)$/i;
var baseHref = '';
if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined)
        baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');
    jQuery('a').each(function() {
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        if (href && (href.match(/^https?\:/i)) && (!href.match(document.domain))) {
            jQuery(this).click(function() {
                var extLink = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'External', 'Click', extLink]);
                if (jQuery(this).attr('target') != undefined && jQuery(this).attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
                    setTimeout(function() { location.href = href; }, 200);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        else if (href && href.match(filetypes)) {
            jQuery(this).click(function() {
                var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
                var filePath = href;
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'Click-' + extension, filePath]);
                if (jQuery(this).attr('target') != undefined && jQuery(this).attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
                    setTimeout(function() { location.href = baseHref + href; }, 200);
                    return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What would be the best way to go about parsing the URL and stopping after it finds the `.pdf` extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the query string before you look for the file extension, you can change this:

```
 var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
 var filePath = href;
```

to this:

```
 var fname = href;
 var query = href.indexOf("?");
 if (query !== -1) {
     fname = href.substr(0, query);
 }
 var extension = (/[.]/.exec(fname)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(fname) : undefined;
 var filePath = fname;
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JV78r/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm still having some trouble getting the tracking code to be injected into the `<a>` element though. Trying a few different things with your answer, will report back with my findings.

Comment: I got this working by changing `if (href && href.match(filetypes))` to `if (fname && fname.match(filetypes))` based on your answer. Thank you!